# Restore an iPod classic without a Mac

Tags: ubuntu, ipod

I'm trying to install RockBox on an old iPod classic (5th gen, video version).

Ubuntu recognized my iPod but RockBox did not, so I inspected the content of the iPod and found 3 partitions, two little and a big one, I reformatted the big one to FAT, thinking it would resolve my issue. It did not...

Now my iPod is constantly rebooting, I can access disk mode and diagnostic mode, but the iPod is not recognized by my Ubuntu nor my Windows system.

What can I do to use my iPod and install RockBox on it?

Comment: iTunes in windows should be able to.

Comment: Even if Windows does not detect my iPod?